# SideMenu didSelect method is not working inSwift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `LGSideMenuController` pod in app to show the side menu on my home screen

I created a function in my **AppDelegate** file like this to show the side menu

```
func rootViewController() {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    let mainViewController = DashboardViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Main)
    let leftViewController = SideMenuViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Main)

    let sideMenuController = LGSideMenuController(rootViewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController),leftViewController: leftViewController, rightViewController: nil)
    sideMenuController.delegate = self
    sideMenuController.leftViewWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 150
    sideMenuController.leftViewPresentationStyle = .slideAbove
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sideMenuController, animated: true)
    appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = sideMenuController
    appDelegate?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

And call it in my **`LoginViewController`** to set the `rootViewController` in the app

```
@IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) { 
    AppDelegate.shared.rootViewController()
}
```

After that I called sideMenu in my `DashboardViewController`

```
import UIKit
import LGSideMenuController

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, LGSideMenuDelegate {


    //MARK:- IBOUTLETS
    //MARK:-
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    //MARK:- VARIABLES
    //MARK:-
    var dashboardItems =  ["Customer", "Sales Men", "Order", "Payment Collection", "News", "Message", "demo", "demo", "demo", "demo"]

    //MARK:- CONSTANTS
    //MARK:-


    //MARK:- VIEW CONTROLLER LIFE CYCLE
    //MARK:-
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sideMenuController?.delegate = self
        addHamburgerMenu()
    }

    override func onHamburgerMenu() {
        self.sideMenuController?.showLeftView(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
    }

}
```

SideMenuController class:

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip
import LGSideMenuController

class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider, LGSideMenuDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        sideMenuController?.delegate = self
    }

    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo { 
        return IndicatorInfo(title: "SideMenu")
    }
}


extension SideMenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sideMenuCell", for: indexPath) as! SideMenuTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("did select is working fine")
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomerListViewController") as! CustomerListViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}

class SideMenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib() 
    }
}
```

when I am clicked side button it is showing the sideMenu but the problem is when I am selecting any item in sideMenu to go to next ViewController it is not working. When I am clicking sendNewRequest it is not working. Please help?

[image]

Comment: Where have you implemented the menu delegate in your class ?

Comment: which delegate method Sir ?

Comment: sideMenuController.delegate = self
 you are setting a delegate, and confirmed to it, have you tried to check what delegate method you need to implement to use or have you used anything already

Comment: Sir edited the question can you check it again

Comment: is there any chance you might forgot to connect the delegate of the tableView in your UIViewController ?

Comment: No Sir I have done all the things when i am clicking cell it is printing the data but it is not going to another view controller :(

Comment: Here, `sideMenuController?.delegate = self` What is the class of **sideMenuController** ?? .. Just below this add `tableView.delegate = self`

Comment: P.S. I am talking about SideMenuViewController , ViewDidLoad.

Comment: @dahiya_boy... Sir I connected my delegate and dataSource of tableView and this is `sideMenuController` inside the pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change didSelectRowAt method in SideMenuViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomerListViewController") as! CustomerListViewController

    let navigationController = sideMenuController!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    sideMenuController?.hideLeftView(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: how to update the LGSideMenuController every time??

Comment: @ArgaPK Try to use the viewWillAppear func in the SideMenuVC.

Comment: @maxwell that won't work as it loaded only once.  you need reload side tableview or whatever you used.

Answer (score 1):

User following code to fix your issue in tableView's didSelect.

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomerListViewController") as! CustomerListViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
sideMenuController?.rootViewController = navigationController
sideMenuController?.rootView = navigationController.view
sideMenuController?.hideLeftView(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

In your current view controller add following method and call in `viewDidLoad()`

```
func addMenuButton() {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_menu").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState.normal) //icon_menu is icon of menu in assets.
    button.tintColor = .white
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(showMenu), for:.touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
}
```

Add button's target method to show menu again.

```
@objc func showMenu() {
    sideMenuController?.showLeftViewAnimated()
}
```

This is working code in my current project. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Sir your code is pushing to the next view controller but it is not showing back button when i am in another view controller

Comment: @wings, I have added my code in above answer to show menu button when open new view controller.

Comment: @MayurKarmur... Ok Sir let me try that

Comment: I just added the pop method in this func `showMenu` to go back to view controller but it is not working

Comment: How to update table view every time the side menu opens??

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in `UINavigationController`.

The navigation not working

```
let objDetail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as! DetailVC?
let mainViewController = sideMenuController!
let navigationVC = mainViewController.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
navigationVC.pushViewController(objDetail!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

It's because of this line, you are telling it to `pushViewController` into a `nil` `navigationController`,

if you print out `self.navigationController` while debugging you would find that it's `nil`.

**Solution**

1- You can create a `navigationController` simply append the desired `UIViewController` to it and present that `navigationController` however this is not preferred for your case.

2- You should get the storyboard identifier of your main navigation controller and instantiate that and then push into it.

```
        let nav = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourNavID") as! UINavigationController
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomerListViewController") as! CustomerListViewController
        nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

Comment: It is not working can you check my func of setting rootView